# How does PM and AM work with crontab in raspberry pi?

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi, debian, reboot

I want to reboot my raspberry pi every day at 4 in the morning because it's the perfect time to reboot because its guaranteed no one will connect to it, As I am hosting a local server on there and just to ensure that it doesn't slow down or anything I want to reboot it.

I heard you can use crontab?

Would it look like this?
`0 0, 4 * * * reboot` ?
Or is this 4 at night?

I don't understand how PM or AM works in this format or system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron uses the 24 hour clock. PM is hours between 12 and 23.

4am every day would be:

```
0 4 * * * reboot
```

(without the extra `0,` you've inserted in yours).

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you explain what the different places and 0s means? Just so I can understand more about the format. Is it like: `Minute, Hour? * * *`?

Answer (score 1):

This line will reboot it @4 am in the morning

```
0 4 * * * reboot
```

I prefer using https://crontab.guru/#00_00_*_* this will help you time your cron events.
This is an excellent page to verify your cron time.